# Purpose of R31 in crystal oscillator

Tags: oscillator, crystal

What is the purpose of using R31 in the below circuit?

[image]

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to give a larger chunk of schematic, or call out both the part number of the chip driving it and the pins each side are connected to.  Since different chips may have different pinouts, call out the pins _by name_.

Comment: "DNP" means "Do Not Populate" - there will be a footprint on the board for that resistor, but the resistor will not be installed.  Perhaps there is another circuit version that does require a resistor there for some reason.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The only clue there is "FOR OSC STARTUP". In the NXP i.MX 6UltraLite [documentation](https://caxapa.ru/thumbs/841145/IMX6ULHDG.pdf) we can find this suggestion:

[image]

This kind of resistor is typically not necessary on MCU internal oscillators, but perhaps there was a problem detected with the chip in testing and the resistor is a 'fix'.

Comment: Thanks for the support. Can you explain how that resistor helps for oscillator start up?

Comment: The data suggests the bias sans resistor is sub-optimal.